# 1-to-n user-agent Communication in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I have implemented the "tompaana" solution for bot-agent-handoff (1 to 1 conversation), but how can I establish a "1 to n" scenario (i.e. one agent handling multiple users after bot escalation)?

I have implemented as per the link given below :

Referred link : https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample.

Comment: I don't have a "real" answer for you,  but I was actually thinking about this this morning, out of interest. One possible option is to have multiple backend bots (say 10 bots for example) that get re-used, so the each agent would be engaging multiple bots, one for each end-user chat in progress. Then, when user 11 comes in, you'd need to implement a queue mechanism, responding to the user that they're in the queue, how many people before them, etc. Like I said, just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented it was using back channel in the directline api. When agent connects pass the agent details as well as session details with the "start conversation". However any mechanism that stores conversation reference of specific chat with the session would work

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities

Comment: Sorry their main page on the repo links are all messed up heres a proper link https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggy-back-on-outgoing-activities The way to use this is to pass through agent data and who they are connecting to. So to bot agent is n seperate chats, but your application internally tracks which chats are associated with each agent

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what are the changes that we have to do in Tompanna solution. Link of this solution is given above.

Comment: I am not familiar with that solution. From a high level standpoint. User makes request -> find agent -> start new chat with pass through information on backchannel -> store that conversation reference with user.

Answer (score 0):

For the intermediate-bot-sample, here is a comment by @tompanna with regards to a call center support scenario [issue](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample/issues/27#issuecomment-468249113):

> I think the best bet to implement a call center, given that one want to use the message router, is to take the [message routing component source](https://github.com/tompaana/bot-message-routing) and customize it based on one's needs. [LiveEngage](https://www.liveperson.com/tags/liveengage) is one that has routing capabilities out-of-the-box, but can be enhanced with custom code. I have implemented a [simple connector for LivePerson](https://github.com/tompaana/liveperson-bot-adapter) service (Node.js). [Ibex Dashboard](https://github.com/Azure/ibex-dashboard) is another OSS project by Microsoft containing enablers for this kind of a scenario (but does not do the job out-of-the-box).

You can take a look at the BotFramework HandOff experimental [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.HandoffBot). Also, there is a Node [sample](https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff) by TDurnford where you can message #list to get a list of users waiting to talk to an agent in the queue, and message #connect to connect to the user waiting at the top of the queue.

Hope this helps.